# Checking multiple columns condition in pandas

Tags: python, pandas

I want to create a new column in my dataframe that places the name of the column in the row if only that column has a value of 8 in the respective row, otherwise the new column's value for the row would be "NONE". For the dataframe `df`, the new column `df["New_Column"] = ["NONE","NONE","A","NONE"]`

```
df = pd.DataFrame({"A": [1, 2,8,3], "B": [0, 2,4,8], "C": [0, 0,7,8]})
```

Comment: What is the expected outcome when two or more columns have a value of 8 in the same row? Both column names (ie "BC")? Only the first/last?

Comment: @DYZ are you implying one should replace the value 8 with the name of the column and the rest of rows with None? If that's the case, I got a bit confused by _creating_ a new column instead of, say, _modifying_ a column.

Comment: @TomasFarias I think the description of the problem is pretty clear (at least for a new contributor). A new column shall be created.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Cool problem.

1. Find the 8-fields in each row: `df==8`
2. Count them: `(df==8).sum(axis=1)`
3. Find the rows where the count is 1: `(df==8).sum(axis=1)==1`
4. Select just those rows from the original dataframe: `df[(df==8).sum(axis=1)==1]==8`
5. Find the 8-fields again: `df[(df==8).sum(axis=1)==1]==8)`
6. Find the columns that hold the `True` values with `idxmax` (because `True>False`): `(df[(df==8).sum(axis=1)==1]==8).idxmax(axis=1)`
7. Fill in the gaps with `"NONE"`

To summarize:

```
df["New_Column"] = (df[(df==8).sum(axis=1)==1]==8).idxmax(axis=1)
df["New_Column"] = df["New_Column"].fillna("NONE")
#   A  B  C New_Column
#0  1  0  0       NONE
#1  2  2  0       NONE
#2  8  4  7          A
#3  3  8  8       NONE
# I added another line as a proof of concept
#4  0  8  0          B
```

Answer (score 1):

You can accomplish this using `idxmax` and a mask:

```
out = (df==8).idxmax(1)
m = ~(df==8).any(1) | ((df==8).sum(1) > 1)

df.assign(col=out.mask(m))
```

```
   A  B  C  col
0  1  0  0  NaN
1  2  2  0  NaN
2  8  4  7    A
3  3  8  8  NaN
```

Answer (score 1):

Or do:

```
df2=df[(df==8)]
df['New_Column']=(df2[(df2!=df2.dropna(thresh=2).values[0]).all(1)].dropna(how='all')).idxmax(1)
df['New_Column'] = df['New_Column'].fillna('NONE')
print(df)
```

`dropna` + `dropna` again + `idxmax` + `fillna`. that's all you need for this.

Output:

```
   A  B  C New_Column
0  1  0  0       NONE
1  2  2  0       NONE
2  8  4  7          A
3  3  8  8       NONE
```